# Embedding in a finitely generated group, up to finite index

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group with a finite subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ embeds into a finitely generated group.  Does $G$ itself embed into a finitely generated group?

Comment: $G/H$ is a finite group, hence it trivially embeds in a finitely generated group (in itself). This does not give any information.

Comment: Oops, sorry, $H$ is supposed to be finite, not finite index!  (Question edited.)

Comment: If you want a direct proof, you could embed $G$ in the the wreath product $H \wr G/H$, which embeds in $H \wr N$ when $G/H < N$, and $H \wr N$ is finitely generated if $N$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group embeds in a finitely generated group if and only if it is countable. You can find a proof in Lyndon and Schupp. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I never heard this before! Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: This is what the HNN extension was invented for.